# how can I store the next text in telegram bot using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot

I want the bot to handle "/add" command in a certain way. I would like to save three inputs from the user (title , text , comments)

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['add'])
def add_to_database(message):
    msg = bot.reply_to(message, """\
We are glad that you are helping us to grow please provide us with the following:-
title of article (the head of the article)
""")
```

the problem is when a user sends "/add" it becomes the message variable for the function , and so I wanna update this variable to the next message that will be sent by the user , I tried something like

`title = updater.message.text`

I want the user to send title of an article and that becomes the variable title, next we ask for the article and store it in another value all in plain text, and so on.

But I got an error like

```
    title = updater.message.text
AttributeError: 'Updater' object has no attribute 'message'
```

Comment: what is `updater` ?

Comment: i was trying to use this
https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.updater.html
i even tried this 
https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.update.html#telegram.Update.message

both seemed fail to work

Comment: `updater` doesn't have `.message` and it can't have access to next message because it  may not exists yet.

Comment: You should rathere create `message_handler` to catch messages which doesn't have commands - i.e `unknow()` - to catch next message. In handler for command  `add` you could set some global variable - ie. `waiting_for_title = True` and when `unknow()` receives next message then check if `waiting_for_title` is `True` (or `waiting_for_text` is `True` or `waiting_for_coments` is `True`)  and add `message.text` to some variable `title` (or `text` or `comments`). After getting `title` it should reset `waiting_for_title` to `False` and `set waiting_for_text = True`

Comment: BTW: it seems there are [examples](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/conversationbot.py) for [ConversationHandlers](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/tree/master/examples) so it may decide what to do with next message - you can set what handler will get next mesage and so after `add` next message may go to handler ie `get_title` and next message may go to handler ie. `get_text`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It is minimal example which uses `ConversationHandler` to get `title`, `text`,  and `comments` in separated messages

You start conversation using command `/add`.

Function `add()` sends message to user with information what to do and it returns value `TITLE` to inform bot that next message has to get function `get_title()`.

Function `get_title()` gets text and keep it in global dictionary as `title`, and it returns value `TEXT` to inform bot that next message has to get function `get_text()`.

Function `get_text()` gets text and keep it in global dictionary as `text`, and it returns value `COMMENTS` to inform bot that next message has to get function `get_comments()`.

Function `get_comments()` gets text and keep it in global dictionary as `comments`, and it display all data from dictionary (but it could save it in database). It returns `ConversationHandler.END` to inform bot that it is end of conversation. It could return `COMMENTS` to get more comments but it would have to keep comments as list in dictionary. And it would need some command to stop getting comments and then save all data.

---

Base on example code [conversationbot.py](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/conversationbot.py) from [documentation](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/tree/master/examples)

---

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, ConversationHandler, MessageHandler, Filters

TOKEN = 'YOUR_TOKEN'

updater = Updater(token=TOKEN, use_context=True)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

# --- structure for data ---

data = {'title': "", 'text': "", 'comments': ""}

# --- states use in conversation ---

TITLE = 1
TEXT = 2
COMMENTS = 3

# --- functions use in conversation ---

# Command Handler which starts conversation
def add(update, context):
    global data # to assign new dictionary to external/global variable

    # create new empty dictionary
    data = {'title': "", 'text': "", 'comments': ""}

    update.message.reply_text("add title, text, comments in separated messages\n\nnow write title")

    # next state in conversation 
    return TITLE

def get_title(update, context):
    data['title'] = update.message.text

    update.message.reply_text(f"title: {update.message.text}\n\nnow write text")

    # next state in conversation 
    return TEXT

def get_text(update, context):
    data['text'] = update.message.text

    update.message.reply_text(f"text: {update.message.text}\n\nnow write comments")

    # next state in conversation 
    return COMMENTS

def get_comments(update, context):
    data['comments'] = update.message.text

    update.message.reply_text(f"comments: {update.message.text}")

    msg = """I got all data

title: {}
text: {}
comments: {}""".format(data['title'], data['text'], data['comments'])

    update.message.reply_text(msg)

    # end of conversation
    return ConversationHandler.END

def cancel(update, context):

    update.message.reply_text('canceled')

    # end of conversation
    return ConversationHandler.END

# --- create conversation ---

my_conversation_handler = ConversationHandler(
   entry_points=[CommandHandler('add', add)],
   states={
       TITLE: [
           CommandHandler('cancel', cancel),  # has to be before MessageHandler to catch `/cancel` as command, not as `title`
           MessageHandler(Filters.text, get_title)
       ],
       TEXT: [
           CommandHandler('cancel', cancel),  # has to be before MessageHandler to catch `/cancel` as command, not as `text`
           MessageHandler(Filters.text, get_text)
       ],
       COMMENTS: [
           CommandHandler('cancel', cancel),  # has to be before MessageHandler to catch `/cancel` as command, not as `comments`
           MessageHandler(Filters.text, get_comments)
       ],
   },
   fallbacks=[CommandHandler('cancel', cancel)]
)                

dispatcher.add_handler(my_conversation_handler)

# --- run bot ---

updater.start_polling()
print('Running... [Press Ctrl+C to stop]')
updater.idle()
print('Stoping...')
updater.stop()
```

---

**EDIT:** something similar with `telebot`. I use global variable `state` and message_handler which catchs unknow messages

```
import telebot 

TOKEN = 'TOKEN'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

#print(bot.get_me())

# --- structure for data ---

data = {'title': "", 'text': "", 'comments': ""}

# --- states use in conversation ---

state = None

TITLE = 1
TEXT = 2
COMMENTS = 3

@bot.message_handler(commands=['add'])
def test(message):
    global state
    global data

    data = {'title': "", 'text': "", 'comments': ""}

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'add title, text, comments in separated messages\n\nnow write title')

    state = TITLE

@bot.message_handler()
def unknown(message):
    global state

    if state == TITLE:
        data['title'] = message.text
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"title: {message.text}\n\nnow write text")
        state = TEXT
    elif state == TEXT:
        data['text'] = message.text
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"text: {message.text}\n\nnow write comments")
        state = COMMENTS
    elif state == COMMENTS:
        data['comments'] = message.text
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"comments: {message.text}")
        msg = """I got all data

title: {}
text: {}
comments: {}""".format(data['title'], data['text'], data['comments'])

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, msg)
        state = None
    #else:
    #    print('unknown message')
    #    bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, 'unknown message')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['cancel'])
def test(message):
    global state

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'canceled')

    state = None

bot.polling()
```

---

**EDIT:** simpler version

```
import telebot 

TOKEN = 'TOKEN'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

# --- structure for data ---

data = {'title': "", 'text': "", 'comments': ""}

# --- states use in conversation ---

bot.state = None # create own value `.state` in `bot` - so I don't have to use `global state`. Similar way I could create and use `bot.data`

TITLE = 1
TEXT = 2
COMMENTS = 3

@bot.message_handler(commands=['add'])
def test(message):
    global data

    data = {'title': "", 'text': "", 'comments': ""}

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'add title, text, comments in separated messages\n\nnow write title')
    bot.state = TITLE

# it has to be before functions which check `bot.state`
@bot.message_handler(commands=['cancel'])
def test(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'canceled')
    bot.state = None

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg:bot.state==TITLE)
def get_title(message):

    data['title'] = message.text

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"title: {message.text}\n\nnow write text")
    bot.state = TEXT

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg:bot.state==TEXT)
def get_title(message):

    data['text'] = message.text

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"text: {message.text}\n\nnow write comments")
    bot.state = COMMENTS

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg:bot.state==COMMENTS)
def get_title(message):

    data['comments'] = message.text

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"comments: {message.text}")
    msg = """I got all data

title: {}
text: {}
comments: {}""".format(data['title'], data['text'], data['comments'])
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, msg)
    bot.state = None

bot.polling()
```

Comment: this works exactly how I wanted , just question though, the only work around through any type of conversation is states? as you suggested??

Comment: module `telegram-bot` uses `states` as default/preferred method for conversations (they have even states' schemas like [this](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/conversationbot.png)) and I expected that `telebot` will have something similar. `states` are aslo popular method also in games. They uses so called [Finite State Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine).

Comment: In `telebot` issues I found [Getting previous send message](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/issues/777) and someone also mentiones [Finite State Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) as solution for this problem. But other person uses `bot.register_next_step_handler(...)` for this - and probably it can be preferred method in `telbot`.